# Accessing a dual monitor system using chrome remote desktop using the dual monitor setup at my place

Tags: remote-desktop

The question is **how do I access both the screens on my dual screens**.

Let us call the machines:

**My laptop** and **My Screen**

**Remote laptop** and **Remote screen**

I want **remote lapotp** on **my laptop** and **remote screen** on **my screen**

I am using chrome remote desktop. I have windows home edition.

Answer (score 5):

When you open chrome remote desktop app, on the right side there is an arrow that opens the settings of the app. There you can set the screen options like full screen or screen selection [screenshot of side bar settings in chrome remote desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6mHi.png)

Answer (score 4):

I've found a workaround. You can open 2 chrome remote desktops on your laptop and open 2 sessions, one to each screen. But you have to use different ways to access, because if you use the same when you open the second session, it'll disconnect the first one.

So one of them you connect to the host using the option "remote access" and the other one you connect using the option "remote support" (this is the one you gotta generate a code). After connected, you select one screen to each session and change both to full-screen. A bit boring doing all these steps, but after done it works well.

Comment: This definitely saved my life! It's not hard to set up and worked like a charm! Now I can basically use the two monitors at home to mirror the two monitors at office.! Thanks a lot

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 You are welcome. I'm glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the arrow on the right side of the remote screen, then choose displays, you can then choose to see 1 display or 2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my work-around.  I change my display settings for that session so that my extra monitors duplicate the main and that changes it to full screen.

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail on how you did this? A step by step guide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SO the only way I have been able to solve this is by spanning the screens on the local desktop, then starting chrome remote desktop, showing both monitors from remote desktop, and going into full screen view. The resolutions are weird, but it does work where you have your one remote laptop screen on laptop screen and then your remote screen on your my screen. its still hit or miss. sometimes it looks great, other times its very fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mac you could take advantage the scree zoom i the accessibility preferences. Just hold control and zoom to the desktop you need to see. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210978#scroll

Answer (score 0):

On the laptop/tablet click the arrow to the right to open up the session options - uncheck the box that says 'scale to fit' then scroll down to displays and choose which screen you want to work with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The described workaround from user Christian Marchiori works very good.

Users from NVIDIA cards or AMD cards can use these 2 options as workaround, that works more easy and allows to move windows from one scrren to the other:

for NVIDIA graphic cards : use the option "Span displays with surround"

for AMD  graphic cards : use the option "Eyefinity"

as a result you get one display eg.with 7680 x 2160 pixel instead of two.

Then you can do fullscreen with "chrome remote desktop" on a dual monitor setup, because the dual monitor is recognized as only one monitor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I use the chrome remote desktop and the TeamViewer at the same time - remote desktop for the first screen and the TeamViewer for the second screen. In this way, you can achieve dual monitor environment remotely. I hope this will help you.